# link between integral and summation

Tags: integration, summation

I've recently found those two equations on Wikipedia but without any further details.

$$\sum_{k=a}^{b} f(k)=\Delta^{-1}f(b+1)-\Delta^{-1}f(a)$$

$$\sum_{k=a}^b f(k) = \int_{[a,b]} f\,d\mu$$

Could someone help me figure it out ? With some examples if possible.

Thanks by advance.

Comment: Mentioning *which* Wikipedia page you found this at would certainly be helpful...

Comment: it won't help much but here it is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Measure_theory_notation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One  way to define an integral on a space X is to find a nice measure on that space (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)), use this measure to define the "integral" of certain basic functions $X \to \mathbb{R}$ and then define the integral of a more general class of functions as the limit of integrals of basic functions that approximate a function in this general class.

Examples.

If we take the counting measure on $\mathbb{N}$ (so the measure of a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ with $n$ elements is $n$), then the resulting "integral" of a function $f: \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$ is just the sum $\sum\limits_{i=1}^{\infty} f(i)$.

If we take the Lebesgue measure on some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}$ and take the basic functions to be finite sums of scaled characteristic functions of Lebesgue measurable subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, then this gives the Lebesgue integral.

Thus, to answer your question, a summation is a particular type of integral and so that is why you encountered the above notation.

I've been rather vague in places here and maybe some of these words are unfamiliar. But I think everything can be looked up easily on wikipedia and so hopefully this will start you on a merry chase through a lot of interesting mathematics.

Comment: ok thanks but what about the other equation : $$\sum_{k=a}^{b} f(k)=\Delta^{-1}f(b+1)-\Delta^{-1}f(a)$$ ?

Comment: I think the link next to that particular equation is fairly helpful. Basically, $\Delta^{-1}$ is a discrete analogue of the indefinite integral where the discrete derivative $\Delta$ is defined by $\Delta f$ is the function $f'$ such that $f'(x)=f(x+1)-f(x)$. So in this particular case, I think the expression on the right is just saying $\sum\limits_{i=- \infty}^{b} f(i)-\sum\limits_{i=- \infty}^{a-1} f(i)$ which is of course equal to $\sum\limits_{k=a}^{b}$.